# Posting volume down/up events using Core Graphics

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics, iokit

I'm trying to post volume button events using Core Graphics. Other types of events are working fine but the volume buttons aren't. I'm creating the event using `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent` and passing in `kVK_VolumeUp` (`0x48`) but it doesn't seem to be working. Other key codes are working (like `kVK_RightArrow` and `kVK_ANSI_Semicolon`), but the volume buttons aren't.

I'm hoping that I'm missing a step here. I tried posting `kVK_F12` but of course, that's F12 and not volume-up. I also tried posting fn+F12 but that didn't work either. Perhaps I need to call `CGEventSetIntegerValueField`?

Am I going to have to drop down a level and use I/O Kit instead of Core Graphics?